# How can I find a list of backlinks by date for a domain?

Tags: seo, domains, backlinks, spam

I have successfully switched my Site A over to Site B (a legacy domain i purchased). I recently have uncovered some shady link building practices in the Site B link profile.

I am trying to find all historical backlinks to Site B pre-domain change so that i can disavow them and only keep the legitimate authoritative links from my original domain (Site A).

With limited cooperation from the previous site owners of Site B, any thoughts as to how i should proceed in finding the spam links from before the domain change?

Answer (score 2):

[Majestic SEO](http://www.majesticseo.com/) is a popular backlink archive. Actually, it believe it's the largest backlink archive available to date.

You can use it (you may need to purchase a subscription) to check the links pointing to Site B to determine what you want to do with that.

Comment: At the time of this post, Ahrefs was the biggest but Majestic is catching up.

Answer (score 0):

[Matt Cutts recommends that you not try to use a domain with a spammy history](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lGUw9oS5csI):

> The way to think about it is there are a lot of spammers
>   out there that do basically what's known as a churn and
>   burn tactic, where they just use as many techniques to try
>   to make domain rank as they can and then as soon as that domain is awful, or bad, or
>   Google has caught it, then they sort of move on and they go on to some other exploit, and they try to tackle it with another domain.
>
> Now what you don't want to do is be the guy who gets caught
>   left holding the bag.  Who buys what looks like a good sounding domain, but
>   actually a spammer has kind of driven into the ground. It's almost like instead of starting from the ground floor, some spammer has come along before you and dug a hole and now when you start out you're already in that hole.

I haven't heard that the disavow tool is helpful for cleaning up completely from a previous owner.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to see blocked resources carefully on your search console and then then act with robots.txt where you can allow only links that you like to be shown on google and to be followed, all other links will not hurt you. If you are using Wordpress or other platforms, I also recommend to use plugins that block harmful spams and protect your links. Hope i helped.

Comment: When you say "blocked resources" are you talking about the "Crawl errors" report?